# Repeating data from database?

Tags: php, mysql, database

Database with the following columns:

[image: Database Columns]

What I pretend with my program is that a user chooses the tags they want so that the exercise corresponding to the chosen tags is shown on the screen. For example, if the user chooses tag 1, exercises 1 and 2 will appear. If you choose tags 1 and 3, exercises 1 and 2 appear.

The problem with my program is that when the user chooses tags 1 and 3, for example, exercises 1 and 2 appear but 2 repeats. Or when you choosing tags 1 and 2, exercise 1 is repeated.

Does anybody know any way so that this does not happen? Only show the exercises once?

Here I show part of my code:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises, union, tags where exercise_id = exercise_id_fk and tag_id = tag_id_fk";

if (!empty($_SESSION['tags_array'])) {
    $sql .= " and (";
    foreach ($_SESSION['tags_array'] as $tagId)
        $sql .= 'tag_id = ' . $tagId . ' or ';

    $sql .= "tag_id = -1);";
}

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["exercise_id"] . ". " .  $row["title"] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT?

Comment: I dont understand you Gordon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem is with your query, please try adding the `group by exercise_id_fk` in your query at last.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises, union, tags where exercise_id = exercise_id_fk and tag_id = tag_id_fk";

if (!empty($_SESSION['tags_array'])) {
    $sql .= " and (";
    foreach ($_SESSION['tags_array'] as $tagId)
        $sql .= 'tag_id = ' . $tagId . ' or ';

    $sql .= "tag_id = -1)";
}
$sql .= ' group by exercise_id_fk';
$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["exercise_id"] . ". " .  $row["title"] . "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Like this? `$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises, union, tags where group by exercise_id = exercise_id_fk and tag_id = tag_id_fk";`

Comment: SELECT * FROM exercises, union, tags where exercise_id = exercise_id_fk and tag_id = tag_id_fk and (tag_id=1 or tag_id=-1) group by exercise_id_fk

Comment: please try this edit. let me know if you got any error.

Comment: Okey I tried and it doesnt appear any error but it just shows exercise 1 if I press tag 1 for example

Comment: SELECT * FROM exercises e
inner join union_table u on u.exercise_id_fk = e.exercise_id
inner join tags t on t.tag_id = u.tag_id_fk
where tag_id = $tag_id
group by u.exercise_id_fk

Comment: try forming this query.

Comment: It works now! Thank you very much! It takes some minutes to show the exercise but finally works :)

Comment: in that case, you can add index to the tag_id_fk.

Comment: You mean like a Datatype in the Database?

Comment: I think he meant creating an index to improve queries performance. I think you should to try to create one in tags table and another in union table. Use this: `CREATE INDEX idx_union_tagid ON union (tag_id_fk);
CREATE INDEX idx_tags_tagid ON tags (tag_id);`

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to try something using GROUP BY expression, like:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM exercises e INNER JOIN union u ON u.exercise_id_fk = e.exercise_id INNER JOIN tags t ON t.tag_id = u.tag_id_fk WHERE 1 = 1";

if (!empty($_SESSION['tags_array'])) {
        $sql .= " and (";
        foreach ($_SESSION['tags_array'] as $tagId)
            $sql .= 't.tag_id = ' . $tagId . ' or ';

        $sql .= "t.tag_id = -1)";
}

$sql .= " GROUP BY e.exercise_id;";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row["exercise_id"] . ". " .  $row["title"] . "<br>";
}
```